# Reading pdf file in ipad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my Ipad application i need to read .pdf files. these pdf files are stored in my server. the size of the pdf files are nearly 20Mb. Normaly in ipad we can view the pdf using UIwebview, but it's not useful in this case. the reason is normaly in iPad the pdf files are downloaded and showed in UIWebview.. but in my case the size maters..so i need another solution to read pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is take the pdf in a spitted fashion.means suppose ur pdf contains 1000 pages download first page and load on the webView and start download for the remaining pages in the background something like  nsoperationquee .so you need to modify in the server side also if you like my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have pdf url that in server right? get the pdf files from the server and store it locally like DB. After that you can display the PDF files from the DB. This is the one time process.Then it not take much time for download.

Or you get the pdf images and display in the uiimageview its simple and easy. But one drawback is you can read the text but not do any action on that i.e., copy the text like that

Thanking you

Comment: how to place pdf in the imageView??is there any way to copy text from the pdf!!